# Angular issue with Interpolation and also implementing elements

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

I have got a problem with String Interpolation.

So I try to make string interpolation according to what the teacher does in the course of Angular
i am doing.

I have a server.component.ts file which is exactly what teacher does in the course.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component ({
    selector: 'app-servers',
    templateUrl: './server.component.html'
})

export class ServerComponent {
serverId = 10;
serverStatus = 'offline'
}
```

And then I try to put it on the server.component.html so it appeared on the browser:

```
<p>Server with ID {{ serverId }} is {{ serverStatus }}</p>
```

I have checked multiple times and it seems like I have exactly the same setting that the teacher showed in the course. He has it written in the browser, and I do not.

Here are my other "settings"
***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  styles: [`
  h1{
    color: red
  }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Wojtek';
}
```

**app.component.html
**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1>Hellloo!!!!</h1>
<input type="text">
<p>{{ name }}</p>
<hr>
<app-success-alert></app-success-alert>
<app-warning-alert></app-warning-alert>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';
import { ServersComponent } from './servers/servers.component';
import { SuccessAlertComponent } from './success-alert/success-alert.component';
import { WarningAlertComponent } from './warning-alert/warning-alert.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent,
    ServersComponent,
    SuccessAlertComponent,
    WarningAlertComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also the thing is with implements OnInit in the export class line, in the course it works, however in my VSCode it does not really want to, any ideas?

Please it you may help me I would be really grateful!

I have tried to watch multiple youtube videos, also I came back to the course to rewatch it

Comment: You shouldn't try to learn from YouTube videos. Read a text book. Where do you use the component?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are missing the server-component in your app-component template. Put `<app-servers></app-servers>` somewhere in your app-component template.

Comment: Did not work unfortunately :/

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Exactly, NG8001: 'app-server' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-server' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-server' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

11 <app-server></app-server>
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

Comment: In your app.module.ts is the path for the import of the ServerComponent correct? Because Angular can't find the ServerComponent.

Comment: Exactly, NG8001: 'app-server' is not a known element ,    
@Component ({
    selector: 'app-servers',
    templateUrl: './server.component.html'
}) take a look at selector and you should change 'app-servers' to 'app-server' and  ...